# Split date into month in data.frame

Tags: r

return,

```
       date            x
 1: 2015-02-10 -1.2070657
 2: 2015-02-11  0.2774292
 3: 2015-04-10  1.0844412
 4: 2015-05-22 -4.5324307
 5: 2015-05-23  2.3497707
 6: 2015-12-15  0.1246677
```

I want to split date into month as follows:

```
  $2015-02      
         date           x
1:  2015-02-10 -1.2070657
2:  2015-02-11  0.2774292
 $2015-04
         date           x
1:  2015-04-10  1.0844412
$2015-05
         date           x
1:  2015-05-22 -4.5324307
2:  2015-05-23  2.3497707
$2015-12
         date           x
1:  2015-12-15  0.1246677
```

How can i do it?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `format` the `date` column in year and month and then `split` them according to it.

```
split(df, format(df$date, "%Y-%m"))


#$`2015-02`
#    date          x
#1 2015-02-10 -1.2070657
#2 2015-02-11  0.2774292

#$`2015-04`
#    date        x
#3 2015-04-10 1.084441

#$`2015-05`
#    date         x
#4 2015-05-22 -4.532431
#5 2015-05-23  2.349771

#$`2015-12`
#    date         x
#6 2015-12-15 0.1246677
```